# Handling "If-None-Match" header with angular resouce?

Tags: angularjs, http-headers, angular-resource

I have an angular app which talks to my rails api via ng resource. In my response I set etag in my header which I get in my response headers but while making the same query again If-None-Match header is not set and in turn my caching doesn't works whereas when i make requests directly via the browser it works correctly. How can I set the received etag in my request headers with $resource

Answer (score 1):

`$resource` doesn't natively support etags, one way of doing it is using `$cachefactory` and `interceptors`. I did a similar [thing](https://github.com/mxparajuli/projeky/blob/master/angular-cache.js) for a project but your mileage may vary.

For a better solution look at [Restangular](http://www.committedcoder.com/restangular-and-etags-pt1.html) or [angular-data](http://angular-data.pseudobry.com/).